# Can create files, but can't modify it?

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab-ci-runner

I've got a problem with permissions. I'm running a gitlab-runner in a shell that should copy files from my repo to a specific directory where it also has access. When these directory, where the gitlab runner should copy the files does not exist, it creates it and copys it without any problem. But after one commit to my repo, the pipeline stucks and I get this error message:

```
$ cp -r api /var/www/example.com
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/www/example.com/api/.git/objects/b9/b63973775876c6be690a53cc82612f7b3c14c9': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/www/example.com/api/.git/objects/73/1d82c36e404eb20984824078d73496995314d3': Permission denied
```

I don't know why because all permissions should be set right and the directory is created by the gitlab-runner itself.

Does anyone know why the runner cant't modify the files inside the directory after the directory is created?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you tried to check permissions? It looks like, you have only read permissions to `example.com`

Comment: Permissionis for the given directory look like this: drwxrwxr-x

Comment: Then owner full permissions, user group full permissions, public read + execute (missing write), so depends which user is owner, which group is owner, and if the given user is permitted to the action, looks like given user belongs to public group

Comment: No didn't helped anything. Same error as before.

Comment: What did not helped? :D I just mentioned you should take a look which user is owner of the given folder, and which group, and then refer to groups of user, which you are using..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give permissions to everyone you can Type `sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/file` into the terminal, replacing `/path/to/file` with the file.
You can also use the command `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/folder` to give permissions to the selected folder and its files

this is not a good solution tho, you should give read-write access to
the gitlab-runner, not everyone!

you can use [setfacl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/setfacl.1.html) for controlling user/group access to a file or folder

```
setfacl -R -m u:gitlab-runner:rwx myfolder
```

-R flag will set permissions recursively to all the subdirectories.

This sets permissions for specific users, without changing the ownership of the directory.